# Round up DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

For my SteamBot I want to store the date and the time when the item is tradable again.

**Example:**

```
// DateNow = 05.06.2019 13:37:00
(+ 7 days due to Steam's trade policy)
// DateNow+7Days = 12.06.2019 13:37:00
// DateIneed = 13.06.2019 09:00:00
```

So the DateTime I need is CurrentDateTime + 7 Days + The rest to 9 o'clock

**This is how far I come:**

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```

Is there any smart way to always get the DateTime I need?

Language is C#

Comment: @Joe That works if the time is before 9, but if it's after 9 the OP seems to want 9 on the next day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if it is before 9 o'clock today, then set the time to 9, else add one day and set the time to 9, should be fairly easy I think.

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
var date = time.Hour <= 9
   ? time.Date.AddDays(7).AddHours(9) 
   : time.Date.AddDays(7).AddHours(9).AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Assuming `time` has previously been set to `DateTime.Now`, your condition should be `time.Hour <= 9`, not `DateTime.Now.Hour <= 9`, for the rare edge case where the clock rolls over to the next day.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not atomic, though I really doubt it would matter in practice, since if it's one millisecond before 9 your real code that does something would probably execute afterwards anyway :)

Comment: But if `time` is 1ns before midnight, and you test `DateTime.Now` 1ns after midnight, you'll fail to add the extra required day.  In any case, it's fixed in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime.Date` field exposes *just* the date of a `DateTime`, you can then add an arbitrary `TimeSpan` to that to set the time of a `DateTime` object to whatever you want;

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).Date.Add(new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0))
```

Check it out in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3X37y

---

Given the hour of the day may be past 9AM already, it's possible to end up with a `DateTime` less than 7 days, to counter this you can check if the hour of the day exceeds what you're going to set the `DateTime` to and add a day if it does, like so;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
dt = dt.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(dt.Hour >= 9 ? 1 : 0, 9, 0, 0))
```

See this one in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lfVGis

Comment: Why add a `TimeSpan` when you can use `AddHours`?

Comment: There's no functional difference (aside from some negligible performance differences), either works fine.

Comment: Output is f.e. 2019-06-12 20:11:22Z 2019-06-12 09:00:00Z but it's one day to early

Comment: Didn't take the hour of the day into account, check Illya's answer; it's a better answer.

Comment: I'd definitely agree, I made this answer in haste. I'll leave it here though because it's still an answer and different enough from Ilya's answer.